# How to build toeplitz matrix in MATLAB manually

Tags: matlab

I need to build a toeplitz matrix in MATLAB called `H`, where `H` has size `256 x 256`, from a vector `h` of size `64 x 1`. I need to fill the matrix `H` by  the `l`-th element row of `H` and `p`-th element columns as below:

`H(l,p) = h(l-p) if 0 <= (l-p) =< 64`. Otherwise, `H(l,p)=0;`

I made the code as below:

```
h = randn(64,1); 

H = zeros(256,256); 
for l= 1:256
    for p = 1 : 256 
        if (l-p <= 64 && l-p >= 0)  
            H(l,p) = h(l-p); 
        end 
    end 
end
```

But, I think there is an error in the code since it doesn't give me the expected results.

How do I obtain a toeplitz matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A problem occurs for `l-p=0`, because `h(0)` would call the zeroth element of `h`, and since MATLAB uses 1-based indexing, that'd crash. Simply remove the equality sign in the check:

```
h = randn(64,1); 

H = zeros(256,256); 
for l= 1:256
    for p = 1 : 256 
        if (l-p <= 64 && l-p > 0)  % Removed the = sign
            H(l,p) = h(l-p); 
        end 
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [`toeplitz`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toeplitz.html):

```
H = toeplitz(h_extended)
```

Where you extended `h` from size 64 with `0` until of size 256.

Comment: Smart solution of course, but the OP stated literally in their title "How to build a toeplitz matrix **manually**" (emphasis mine). I guess the OP has to clarify whether `toeplitz` is manual enough or not...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a manual way that uses [vectorization](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) with [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) instead of loops:

```
t = 1:numel(h);
H = h(abs(t-t.')+1);
```